# Please explain this equation

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

$f(x,y)$ be continuous in the rectangle $R$ given by $a\leq x \leq b,{\ }\alpha \leq y \leq \beta$.
$$v(x,y)=\int_{\alpha}^{y}f(x,\eta)d\eta, \quad u(x,y)=\int_{a}^{x} v(\xi,y) d\xi$$
Applying the formula 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dy=\int_{a}^{b}f_{x}(x,y)dy$$
We find
$$u_{y}(x,y)=\int_{a}^{x}v_{y}(\xi,y)d\xi=\int_{a}^{x}f(\xi,y)d\xi$$
and thus
$$u(x,y)=u(x,\alpha)+\int_{\alpha}^{y}u_{y}(x,\eta)d\eta$$
Please explain the last formula, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x$.  Define $\phi(y) = u(x,y)$.  Then $\phi'(y) = u_y(x,y)$ so that
$$u(x,y) - u(x,\alpha) = \phi(y) - \phi(\alpha) = \int_\alpha^y \phi'(\eta) \, d\eta =\int_\alpha^y u_y(x,\eta) \, d\eta.$$

Comment: That’s it! thank you very much!